# How to write a lambda function for keras layers, for vector matrix multiplication

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

In the case of dot(), it takes the dot product,  mathematically defined as: a.b = sum(a_i * b_i), but how to write a lambda function in keras for a*b=product (a_i * b_i) and forwarding this input to next layer

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Essentially we are doing the dot product with multiplication for a `(None, 10)` sized input and a `(10,20)` sized input. This results in a `(None, 20)` sized output.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

inp1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,))
inp2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(10,20))
prod_out = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(K.prod(x[0],axis=1, keepdims=True), K.prod(x[1],axis=0, keepdims=True)))([inp1, inp2])
model = tf.keras.models.Model([inp1,inp2], prod_out)
model.summary()
```

Comment: Input shape(None,75) ,next layer shape(75,3) and output layer shape(3,1) , where the last layer must be calculated as ( (H31*w1)*(H32*w2)*(H33*w3))

Comment: @karunreddy it's not clear what you want to do. Update your question with a more clear explanation of what input/output shapes expected and what h31, w1, h32, w2, ... are.

Comment: Input shape(None,75) ,next layer(Hidden layer 1) shape is (75,3), and next layer(Hidden layer 2) shape is (3,1).For the last layer, the output must be calculated as ( (H21*w1)*(H22*w2)*(H23*w3)), where H21,H22,H23 will be the outcome of Hidden layer 2, and w1,w2,w3 will be constant weight which are not trainable. So how to write a lambda function for the above outcome.